# How can I get language translated key and value in controller using laravel5.4 json localization?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have created json file (lang->de->facilityMessages.json) for localization. But when I access the localization inside controller I am getting no result.

**facilityMessages.json**.

```
{
    "Wifi"                                     : "WLAN",
    "shower available"                         : "Dusche vorhanden",
}
```

FacilityController.php

```
public function index()
{
  $wifi = __('facilityMessages.shower available');
  dd($wifi);      
}
```

**.env**

```
APP_LOCALIZATION=de
```

**config->app.php**

```
'locale' => env('APP_LOCALIZATION'),
```

Comment: Laravel provide multi-language feature by default, refer this [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/localization)

Comment: Tried `$wifi = echo __('facilityMessages.shower available');` ?

Comment: I tried `dd(echo __('facilityMessages.Wifi'));` but showing  `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)`

Comment: no need to use `echo` within `dd` what do you get when `dd( __('facilityMessages.Wifi')` ?

Comment: I tried `dd( __('facilityMessages.shower available'));` but result is showing like `"facilityMessages.shower available"` not showing the translated result.

Comment: Have you tried `trans("facilityMessages.shower available")` ?